# mPDF и шапка таблицы

Tags: php, pdf, header, mpdf

Кто знает, как перенести шапку таблицы на следующую страницу при формировании PDF?

Comment: https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf если что

Answer (score 2):

```
<table>
<thead> <!-- Вот всё, что в thead, и будет использоваться в качестве шапки таблицы на каждой странице -->
  <tr>
     <td>Столбец 1</td>
     <td>Столбец 2</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>Данные</td>
     <td>Данные</td>
  </tr>
...
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Отличный пример в [документации](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/addpage.html#examples). Работает это очень просто (поясняю первый пример):

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

$mpdf->WriteHTML('Your Introduction');
$mpdf->AddPage();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Your Book text');
```

- Создали объект `$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();`;
- Записали в него данные в первую страницу;
- Создали страницу и все последующие данные будут добавляться на добавленную страницу (`$mpdf->AddPage())`;
- Добавили данные на новую страницу.